# Is the use of the RETURNING INTO clause faster than a separate SELECT statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

1)

```
update foo set bar = bar + 1 where a = 123;
select bar into var from foo where a = 123;
```

2)

```
update foo set bar = bar + 1 where a = 123 RETURNING bar into var;
```

I assume the second is faster as it appears to require one less trip to the database. Is this true?

Comment: It is interesting topic. I would say it is faster. One needs to write a small program to test it. But where returning is useful is in delete. Because you can't Delete-Select. But you can Delete-Returning.

Comment: These alternatives are not, technically, equivalent. The first may raise TOO_MANY_ROWS (unless `a` has a unique constraint) whereas the second will not. Even if `a` is a unique identifier, the first may raise NO_DATA_FOUND whereas the second won't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as I thought:

Often, applications need information about the row affected by a SQL operation, for example, to generate a report or take a subsequent action. The INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements can include a RETURNING clause, which returns column values from the affected row into PL/SQL variables or host variables. This eliminates the need to SELECT the row after an insert or update, or before a delete. As a result, fewer network round trips, less server CPU time, fewer cursors, and less server memory are required.

[Taken from Oracle docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/12_tune.htm#43345)

Comment: Thank you T.S. I thought so as well, but I wondered if Oracle only made it appear to take one trip, while behind the scenes it was just executing a SELECT INTO statement to offer us syntactical sugar.

Comment: I never thought it was syntactical sugar. I thought it was like the trigger. While changing data, Oracle has both values (update) and can do something with them, like 'Return' to caller. In this case, only one value can return, new when there is one, or deleted

Comment: Please make a better effort to review edits before you vote to approve them.